# Can a catalog pdf of images like the attached images be generated by ITEXT library?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, catalog

[This as a catalog List of products]
And when click on Add just need to redirect to external page

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, itext (both 5.5.x and 7.x) can add text, bitmaps, and paths to the content of pdf pages, and it can add links to the annotations of pdf pages. Which specific problems do you have with these tasks?

Comment: Also the itext open source successor called [openPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF) can do that...